# PHP transliterate specify locale

Tags: php, locale, icu, transliteration

I am using [PHP Transliterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php) (from php5-intl, using ICU) to transliterate CJK to Latin (Romanization), problem is, I need some ways to specify the input locale so that Japanese Kanji are not romanized into Chinese Pinyin (as they often share the same [utf8 character](http://www.unicode.org/faq/han_cjk.html#3)).

For example:

`transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; Lower();', $input);`

`中国オタク界 => zhong guo otaku jie`

while i would like to get:

`中国オタク界 => chuu goku otaku kai`

Any idea?

---

Further research on the [ICU site](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general) suggest the problem might be that `Han-Latin` only follow Pinyin transliteration, so I am looking for a way to allow php5-intl to tell ICU to use Romaji transliteration instead (I haven't found such id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `Han-Latin` means pinyin. ICU transliterators come from [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org) (I'll update the userguide to make this clear). ICU already can convert kana (hira/kata) to latin, but Kanji has more than one reading, so you won't find what you are looking for with a simple table-based conversion.

**edit:**  so to summarize, ICU will not do what you want without writing rules, nor does  it seem to me likely to be simple to do with your own rules due to how the Japanese language works.

Comment: thx for confirming this, wikipedia seem to suggest CLDR mainly use ruleset from BGN/PCGN romanization, which doesn't appear to contain Kanji specific rules. So what i am trying to do is a lot more difficult than my initial guess (at least, to do it correctly require far more efforts)...

Comment: see wikipedia on Japanese kanji, multiple readings for each kanji.

Comment: do you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLDR ? Have you visited CLDR's own site or mailing list? http://cldr.unicode.org ?  That's more authoritative than wikipedia (I don't know where the "a lot of it" sentence came from. )

Comment: yep, I did some search on CLDR main site and found few topics regarding Kanji in particular. Being native chinese speaker and japanese reader myself, I do know the core difficulty to their transliterations. my question is mostly about finding a solution similar to `Han-Latin`, but it seems there is no open-source solution just yet.

Answer (score 3):

This is a script that I came up with to test all the different traliterators available chained with `Latin-ASCII; Lower();`, but non of them produce the result which you seek. You could try some other Kanji and try to pick a transliterator other than `Any-Latin`.

```
$scripts = transliterator_list_ids();

foreach ($scripts as $script) {
    echo $transliterated = transliterator_transliterate(
        $script . '; Latin-ASCII; Lower();',
        '中国オタク界'
    ) . ' in ' . $script . "\n";
}
```

These ones produced something meaningful and didn't act in the same way as `Any-Latin`: `JapaneseKana-Latin/BGN`, `Katakana-Latin`

Comment: thx for the research effort. i will see what i can do with it.

Comment: bounty to you sir, but unfortunately i haven't found a way to do kanji romanization without writing custom rules (see my question update). maybe you have further insights?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility I could think of would be to set the locale using...

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ja_JP");
```

You can then apply the various [formatting functionality in PHP](http://books.google.com/books?id=-E7_x1uW-GgC&pg=PA220&lpg=PA220&dq=php+specify+locale+in+transliteration&source=bl&ots=ncwFjaDxqg&sig=EE6kHmdyHublNLogNZxCMqTrnAE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=i1suU_byIvGgyQHbxoDIBg&ved=0CFQQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=php%20specify%20locale%20in%20transliteration&f=false) to format the text the way you want it before running through the transliterator.